# on.exit call via eval fires before function ends

Tags: r

Any idea why the eval implementation fires the callback before the function ends?

```
# on.exit fires on exit
exit_test1 = function(){
  on.exit(expr = message('close'))
  message('hello')
}
exit_test1()
#> hello
#> close

# on.exit fires before exit
exit_test2 = function(){
  eval(parse(text = "on.exit(expr = message('close'))"))
  message('hello')
}
exit_test2()
#> close
#> hello
```

Comment: `on.exit` adds stuff to the wrong frame stack. Why are you using `eval` with `on.exit`?

Comment: I'm exploring tracking complex algorithm flow, which means logging when functions end. Eval would enable me to modularise the logging with R6-based OOP approach.  Not critical I know, but it would mean I could reduce the logging code to a single call in each function rather than have lots of distributed code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is mentioned in the documentation for [`eval_bare`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/eval_bare.html). `eval` does not evaluate `on.exit()` in the correct frame environment.

```
exit_test2 = function() {
  exit_cmd = quote(on.exit(expr = message('close 2')))
  message('hello')
  rlang::eval_bare(exit_cmd)
  message('hello')
}
exit_test2()
#> hello
#> hello
#> close 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Further to @Paul's solution in fact I need a string to be executed, so this is the solution:

```
exit_test2 = function() {
  exit_cmd = quote(on.exit(expr = eval(parse(text="message('close')"))))
  rlang::eval_bare(exit_cmd)
  message('hello')
}
exit_test2()
#> hello
#> close
```